# Retrieve MySQL entry from a sub/child table

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the poor title description. I'm not quite sure how to phrase what I'm asking.

I have 3 tables I need to query; 'person', 'portfolio', and 'file_store'.
A 'person' can have one or more 'portfolio'(s), and each portfolio can have one or more files in 'file_store' (I'm storing images in this table).
Using the person_id column in 'person' as the cross-reference, I want to get the 1st image in the 1st portfolio. This is so I can match the user who's logged in with an image that'll be used as their main profile image.
The query I'm running is (using PHP):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT file_store_id FROM file_store INNER JOIN portfolio WHERE person_person_id='$id'"); 
$personProfileImage = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
$personProfileImage = $personProfileImage[0];
```

$id being the person_id of the user logged in (this variable is correct and tested).

But I'm not getting what I'm expecting.
$personProfileImage is always the 1st file_store_id entry and not the file_store_id associated with the person_id.
I have to admit I'm not fully understanding MySQL queries yet... Be gentle...

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: It would be usefull to see a sql describe, to see your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some outside help and the solution was to break the query into two parts and use 'min':

```
SELECT min(portfolio_id) FROM portfolio WHERE person_person_id = '$id'

SELECT min(file_store_id) FROM file_store WHERE portfolio_portfolio_id = $OldestPortfolioID
```